# Is it possible to create a type in typescript that represents all strings except for a set of string literals?

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I would like to use typescript overloading to provide intellisense for a function I'm writing. The signatures only differ by parameter type. The problem I'm having is that if someone passes in something that matches param1 in the first overload, but a param2 that doesn't, then it will fall through to the generic overload. I would like that to not be accepted and have intellisense mark it as an error.

I've tried using conditional typing using Exclude<> which didn't work.

```
type Exclusion = "Invalid";
type ExcludeString = Exclude<string, Exclusion>;

func(param1: "Activate", param2: (value: SomeInterface) => any): void;
func(param1: ExcludeString, param2: (value: any) => any): void;
```

When I call `func("Activate", (value: NotSomeInterface) => console.log("Invalid"));` I would like intellisense to tell the user there's an error. Instead, nothing happens due to the fall through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't define the type directly, `Exclude<string, Exclusion>` will actually just result in `string` typescript does not really have the concept of a negated type. There is a proposal to allow something similar ([Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)) but it's not yet part of the language (at the time of writing 3.3 is the latest version).

All this being said, we can get a similar effect if we are talking about a function parameter that should not be of a specific value. To do this we need a generic type parameter to capture the actual type of the string passed in. Then we can type the parameter as `Exclude<T, Exclusion>` and this will yield the expected errors:

```
type Exclusion = "Invalid";
type ExcludeString = Exclude<string, Exclusion>;

function func<T extends string>(param1: Exclude<T, Exclusion>): void {

} 

func("SS")
func("Invalid") // error
```